# Bash exporting multiple functions

Tags: bash, sh

Is there a cleaner/DRYer way to export multiple functions than how I am doing it here, just repeating the `export -f` command over and over?

```
foo() {
  echo "foo"
}

bar() {
  echo "bar"
}

baz() {
  echo "baz"
}

export -f foo
export -f bar
export -f baz
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`export` takes multiple arguments. You can do:

```
export -f foo bar baz
```